# What happens to the promise if we don't await for it

Tags: javascript

I have this function to play audio using a given source and it works fine:

```
function sfxPlay(source) {
  let sfxAudio = new Audio(`${source}`);
  sfxAudio.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
  sfxAudio.play();

  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    sfxAudio.addEventListener("ended", function () {
      sfxAudio.currentTime = 0;
      resolve();
    });
  });
}
```

I will use it inside an async function like this:

```
await sfxPlay(source.mp3);
```

The question is what if I want to use the function without `await`? Does this make any errors if later I use it with await again... what happens to that promise when we don't await for it?!

**EDIT:**
I mean if we have the function like this inside function A:

```
sfxPlay(source.mp3);
```

Is it acceptable to use it inside function B like this?

```
await sfxPlay(source.mp3);
```

Comment: It's like asking what happens to an object that's returned from a function if you don't assign it. It just gets cleaned up by the garbage collector.

Comment: Without using await, a promise is returned, which you can use as per need.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you don't use await, you can still use the promise, you just have to wait on it manually using `.then` (the promise is just returned as a normal object):

```
sfxPlay(source).then(()=>{
    // ...
});
```

Otherwise, if you don't use it, nothing good or bad will happen by default - the code inside the promise will still run, but nothing will happen when you call `resolve`.

If you call `reject`, however, then nothing will handle the rejection; which *is* bad, as it throws an error on most platforms. So make sure you never use `reject` unless you have a matching `.catch` for it (note also that a `try` / `catch` statements don't work for this particular type of error). Thanks to @T.J. Crowder for pointing this out.

You can mix the two methods without any issues.

Comment: @foxer Awesome, I'm glad I could help! If this solves your problem, could you please mark it as accepted using the checkmark icon to the left of my answer?

Comment: *"...nothing good or bad will happen..."* That depends on your definition of "bad." If the promise is rejected and nothing handles the rejection, the host will report an unhandled rejection in the console/output. When Node.js sees an unhandled rejection, it currently says *"Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code."* E.g., at some point, Node.js may terminate on unhandled rejections -- definitely "bad." :-)

Comment: @foxer - Please see my note above. You may not be using Node.js (or Deno, the latest from Ryan Dahl and crew), but for anyone who is...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Cheers, thanks for pointing that out. I've updated the answer to note that

Comment: Do you mind clarifying "the code inside the promise will still run, but nothing will happen when you call `resolve`."? I suppose you mean that `resolve` is called (i.e., by the function's code) but it's a bit unclear. For example, a newbie might interpret this as the programmer calling `resolve` explicitly, which might or might not be possible if you're referring to `Promise.resolve` or to the `resolve` function arg in the `Promise` constructor.

Comment: It's not really true to say "nothing will happen when you call `resolve`". Something will happen, the promise will be resolved. If it is resolved with a non-thenable then it will be fulfilled otherwise it will adopt the state of the thenable. If you truly don't use it then nothing will happen beyond that. If you don't await on it but you do use it to resolve another promise then that promise will be be fullfilled when this is one is fullfilled. Or if you call `then` or `finally` then those callbacks will be scheduled.

Comment: @uzluisf Yes you are correct. It is the function passed to the promise constructor that has to call `resolve`. I think what the author meant was "nothing will happen when `resolve` is called" (whenever that may be).

Comment: This answer is in context to the original question, in which the OP shows an example where they call the `resolve` argument passed into the promise; and then asks what happens if they don't await it. And the answer to that is, for all intents and purposes, nothing --- sure the promise object goes through a state change and is fulfilled, but if nothing has a reference to it, nothing is awaiting it, and nothing has called `then`, `catch` or `finally`, then from high level perspective nothing will happen when `resolve` is called. And that's fine! You don't _have_ to wait or handle the resolution

Answer (score 10):

If you just call the function and don't do anything with the promise it returns, it means the result of it settling is never handled, which can be fine or can be a problem. There are three things that can happen with the promise (whether you handle them or not):

1. The promise never settles, in which case it doesn't matter that you don't handle fulfillment or rejection since neither of them occurs. :-)
2. The promise is fulfilled. In that case, there's no problem at all. It's just like calling a function and not using its return value.
3. The promise is rejected. This is just like not handling an exception that's thrown (at all, not in the function itself and not in the function(s) that call it, leaving the exception to work its way up to the host environment). At a minimum, the host will report an "unhandled rejection" to the console or output. Some hosts may terminate your program at that point. For instance, the current (as of this edit) version of Node.js (v17.1.0) terminates the process when an unhandled rejection occurs (though there is a [global way](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#event-unhandledrejection) to handle otherwise-unhandled rejections). You may not be using Node.js, but it's not the only host that may start handling unhandled rejections this way.

So you probably want to use the promise, at least to catch errors. If your call is in an `async` function, `await` will do that — but will also hold up the settlement of the promise from the `async` function the `await` is in. In a non-`async` function, or in an `async` function where you don't want to wait for settlement, use `catch` on the promise:

```
sfxPlay(source).catch(()=>{
    /* ...handle/report the error (or just suppress it, if that's appropriate
       [which it sometimes, though rarely, is])...
    */
});
```