# What happens with unhandled promises in Node.js Express?

Tags: node.js, express

I have аn express route in which I call an async function. I don't want express wait till function be executed.
Maybe it already works as I want, but I don't know how to check and prove it.

I have something like this:

```
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  asyncFunctionCall();

  res.end();
});
```

In `asyncFunctionCall` I run slow HTTP-request. If main route logic will be executed before request, I don't want to wait it, but I want to return response to user.

Will Node.js wait until it ends or my http request will run in background without user-request?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What happens to the promise if we don't await for it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61834275/what-happens-to-the-promise-if-we-dont-await-for-it)

Comment: I realize your question is not _exactly_ about promises but most things still apply. Node.js will start executing your async function, then give control back to the request handler, which will go on to `res.end()`. The async operations will still run in background. The catch here is to be mindful of potential exceptions in the async function.

Comment: Oh and I realized the title of your question does mention promises.

Comment: I was afraid that Express perform async functions in another way (waiting till all started calls end while request in processing). Thanks for your explaining!

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32384449/can-i-fire-and-forget-a-promise-in-nodejs-es7